# Updating state item's quantity (React and useReducer)

Tags: reactjs, state

I am trying to build a shopping cart so that when a dispatch is called an item is added to the useReducer state and then rendered elsewhere in the app accordingly via a provider.

My issue is although I can add the item to the state's array, I don't want it to add a whole new second item to the array when someone buys two (or more) of the same item.

Instead it should increment the existing state item's quantity property.

I have made a Codesandbox to hopefully illustrate this. When clicking "Add" it's obviously adding duplicates of 'Test Item' to the array but after the first instance it should instead increment the existing item's "quantity" property and thus the number of items in the array remains at 1.

I have tried a combination of .find, .filter, .map but can't seem to get there, and being new to all this it's become highly frustrating.

https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-ramanujan-pjyw7?file=/src/App.js

Any help is appreciated..
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use findIndex to see if the item has already been added, if it has increment the quantity for the item and if it's not set the quantity to 1.

Something like this.

```
   case "ADD_ITEM":
        let quantity = 0;
        const checkIndex = state.items
                          .findIndex(item => item.id === action.payload.id);
        
        if (checkIndex === -1) {
          quantity = 1;
          return {
            ...state,
            items: [...state.items, 
              { ...action.payload, quantity: quantity }]
          };
        }
      quantity = state.items[checkIndex].quantity += 1;
        
      return {
        ...state,
        ...action.payload, quantity: quantity
      };
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but as you'll see it now increments the total quantity of the item by 2, after the first instance. So on the first "add" it will correctly add the new item to the array (cart). But when you add another, that item's total quantity increments by 2 to 3, instead of by 1 to 2.

Comment: I did notice something strange like that happening but didn't have a chance to debug - I'll look into it further and update the answer if I find a fix.

Comment: For what it's worth, this is the only way I could get it working. It appears mutating the original state was a big no-no..

https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-ramanujan-pjyw7?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Yes it is a big no-no.